# BlackBerry priv: double tap to wake up isn't working

Tags: blackberry

All of a sudden from yesterday morning, double tap screen to wakeup the phone isn't working. I read few forums where I understood even hard reset isn't working.

Please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got fixed automatically this morning. It was clearly not a software issue as there was no update. I suspect it might be the cause of placing the phone's screen face down few days before this issue, which got fixed when I stopped doing so.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have had this problem sometime with my Oneplus X. Sometimes this is a bit buggy and you have to turn the screen on and off which will result in a refresh. Problem solved. Even if it is not the way one would prefere this, but if you wanted to fix this in another way you would have to tune the kernel. If you want to do this... OK, but I don't think this is worth it.